# Why would my deploy.js return this? Error: factory runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction"

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, hardhat, alchemy

I'm using Alchemy API with Hardhat and every time I run the deploy script I get the above error. I am also getting requests to my API every time I run this and the method is eth_accounts, in the request the Params Raw Request the API is getting says this:

```
{ jsonrpc:"2.0", method:"eth_accounts", params:[ ], id:1 }
```

The Return Raw Response is:

```
{ jsonrpc:"2.0", id:1, result:[ ] }
```

It can't possibly be that my Keys aren't working if I am getting requests and responses to my API. I have tried every type of deploy and getContractFactory function and combination. Does this have to do with Metamask maybe? Is there something with the signer that I am missing?

Here is my hardhat.config:

```
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();


const { API_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
    defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
    networks: {
      sepolia: {
        url: `${API_KEY}`,
        account: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
        gas: 2100000,
        gasPrice: 8000000000,
        saveDeployments: true,
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: I suspect a configuration error in the hardhat.config.js file.
Perhaps you need to change the RPC url
You can tell more exactly if you provide more data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are somethings that I think is not correct in hardhat configurations.

- private keys doesn't starts with `0x`
- the parameter `account` should be `accounts`
- you didn't provided the chainId

Here is the hardhat configurations.

```js
...
networks: {
  sepolia: {
    url: `${API_KEY}`,
    accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
    gas: 2100000,
    gasPrice: 8000000000,
    saveDeployments: true,
    chainId: 11155111,
  }
}
...
```

Try these things and I think the problem will be solved.

Just get your private key and paste it as it is in you `.env` file, without adding any additional data, and check results.

Comment: I had originally just pasted in my private key without adding that and got an error that there were not enough bytes. It wouldn't even process a transaction until I added the 0x. I did try deploying just now without it again and I am still getting the same error that is on the original question of this post: Factory runner does not support sending transactions.

Comment: I apologize for not understanding the question well. I noticed that you are not adding the chainId of the sepolia network, try to add this parameter: `chainId: 11155111`. And I noticed too that are writing `account`, write `accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]` and check the results.

Comment: Wow, I think that actually worked! Thank you! Of course I knew you could add the chainId but Alchemy Docs made it seem unimportant.

Comment: You are welcome. I will edit the answer to be a correct answer in the future